# how to bind data to recyclerView from local JSON file

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I had one learning project, that requires to get data from JSON local file, now I faced a problem with images on recyclerView loaded with Glide, the photos were not showing in it. Other than that, I had to send another data from the JSON file to **DetailsActivity**, and I still didn't figure it the way to approach it, any suggestions??

here are the 3 lists of sample JSON files;

```
{
    "users": [{
            "username": "JakeWharton",
            "name": "Jake Wharton",
            "avatar": "@drawable/user1",
            "company": "Google, Inc.",
            "location": "Pittsburgh, PA, USA",
            "repository": 102,
            "follower": 56995,
            "following": 12
        },
        {
            "username": "amitshekhariitbhu",
            "name": "AMIT SHEKHAR",
            "avatar": "@drawable/user2",
            "company": "@MindOrksOpenSource",
            "location": "New Delhi, India",
            "repository": 37,
            "follower": 5153,
            "following": 2
        },
        {
            "username": "romainguy",
            "name": "Romain Guy",
            "avatar": "@drawable/user3",
            "company": "Google",
            "location": "California",
            "repository": 9,
            "follower": 7972,
            "following": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

here's the model class;

```
@Parcelize
data class User(
    val name: String,
    val username: String,
    val company: String,
    val avatar: String,
    val location: String,
    val repository: Int,
    val follower: Int,
    val following: Int
) : Parcelable
```

the adapter ;

```
class CostumAdapter(
    private var context: Context,
    private var userName: ArrayList<String>,
    private var name: ArrayList<String>,
    private var avatar: ArrayList<String>,
    private var company: ArrayList<String>,
    private var location: ArrayList<String>,
    private var repository: ArrayList<Int>,
    private var followers: ArrayList<Int>,
    private var following: ArrayList<Int>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CostumAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var imageJs: ImageView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.iv_img_json) as ImageView
        var nameUser: TextView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_name_json) as TextView
        var userName: TextView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_username_json) as TextView
        var company: TextView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_company_json) as TextView

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_json, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.nameUser.text = name[position]
        holder.userName.text = userName[position]
        holder.company.text = company[position]
        Glide.with(this.context)
            .load(avatar[position])
            .circleCrop()
            .into(holder.imageJs)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return name.size
    }
}
```

here's the main activity ;

```
class JsonDataActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var userName: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    var name: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    var avatar: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    var company: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    var location: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    var repository: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
    var followers: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
    var following: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_json_data)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_jsondata)
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        try {
            val obj = JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset())
            val userArray = obj.getJSONArray("users")
            for (i in 0 until userArray.length()) {
                val userDetail = userArray.getJSONObject(i)
                userName.add(userDetail.getString("username"))
                name.add(userDetail.getString("name"))
                avatar.add(userDetail.getString("avatar"))
                company.add(userDetail.getString("company"))
                location.add(userDetail.getString("location"))
                repository.add(userDetail.getInt("repository"))
                followers.add(userDetail.getInt("follower"))
                following.add(userDetail.getInt("following"))
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val costumAdapter = CostumAdapter(
            this@JsonDataActivity,
            userName,
            name,
            avatar,
            company,
            location,
            repository,
            followers,
            following
        )
        recyclerView.adapter = costumAdapter

    }

    private fun loadJSONFromAsset(): String {
        val json: String?
        try {
            val inputStream = assets.open("githubuser.json")
            val size = inputStream.available()
            val buffer = ByteArray(size)
            val charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8
            inputStream.read(buffer)
            inputStream.close()
            json = String(buffer, charset)
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            return ""
        }
        return json
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: As I saw Glide problem, "avatar": "@drawable/user3", it is not a url, I think you should check it

Comment: yes, it is from a local drawable, any suggestions on how to get the data?

Comment: Could you try int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("image_"+myChoice, "drawable", "com.myapp.mypackage");
if(resId == 0) {
    resId = R.drawable.default;
}
imageView.setImageResource(resId);

Comment: would you mind more detail specified on how to get to the path?